# How can I request all the elements of a multiple select in HTML?

Tags: python, html, forms, get, request

I have created a dropdown list in HTML that allows the selection of multiple elements. Is there any way I can obtain all the selected values (in list format) via Python code? My current code (see below) only retrieves one word of one selected value.

Code for multiple drop down list (within form):

```
<br /><label for "colors">Colors:</label>
    <select name = "colors" id = "colors" multiple>
         <option value="red">RED</option>
         <option value="blue">BLUE</option>  
         <option value="green">GREE</option>       
    </select><br />
```

Code for requesting form elements:

```
topics_list = request.forms.get("colors")
```

Comment: Have you tried : topics_list = request.forms.get_list("colors"). It works with form method post !

Comment: Note: the `<br>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 3):

you should try getlist function as like follow

```
topics_list = request.form.getlist('colors')
```